# aggregated number

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve this problem but couldnt come  up with anything ...

we will name a number "aggregated number" if this number has the following attribute:
just like the Fibonacci numbers
1,1,2,3,5,8,13.....

the digits in the number can divided into several parts, and the later part is the sum of the former parts.

```
like 112358, because 1+1=2, 1+2=3, 2+3=5, 3+5=8
122436, because 12+24=36
1299111210, because 12+99=111, 99+111=210
112112224, because 112+112=224
```

Sorry for incomplete question we need to write to function to test whether a number is aggregated or not ?
any ideas please  help

Comment: Can you phrase your question as, well, a question?  It is hard to answer as is.

Comment: There is no question here,

Comment: Ok, what have you tried?

Comment: what i think is run two loops and then check for every substring that can be potential sum  for the next characters ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're stuck, try to break the problem out into simpler solvable chunks.  For example to get you started:

```
/**
 * Returns true if the provided number is an aggregated number
 *
 * @param potentialAggregatedNumber The number to check.
 */
boolean isAggregated (potentialAggregatedNumber){
    for(numDigits=1; numDigits <= (potentialAggregatedNumber.length/2); numDigits++){
        if(isAggregatedForFirstNumberLength(potentialAggregatedNumber, numDigits) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
  * Returns true if aggregated number when the first number has numDigits digits.
  *
  * @param potentialAggregatedNumber The number to check.
  * @param numDigits The number of digits the first sub-number should have.
  */
boolean isAggregatedForFirstNumberLength(potentialAggregatedNumber, numDigits){
    //your code 
}
```

Comment: This does not help much. And dividing by 3 is wrong.

Comment: @Dialecticus: To be an "aggregated number", it must have at least 3 parts:  two numbers to add and one as the sum.  I made the assumption that the second number would be of equal or greater value, but I guess "11011" could be an aggregate number by his definition now that I think about it.  I've revised to reflect this.

Comment: @Dialecticus: Also, my intent is to point him in the right direction, not to give him the full answer.  `isAggregatedForFirstNumberLength` is definitely a simpler function to write than `isAggregated`, so if he continues along the path of defining the need for simpler and simpler functions, Sree will eventually reach a working algorithm.  Go Sree! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you have the number of digits of first two numbers you have everything you need to check the aggregated number. You just have to generate all valid combinations of digits for first two numbers. Sum of digits should not be larger than half of all digits, because otherwise third number, sum of first two numbers, would not fit into the remainder of aggregate number. Best way to generate all combinations of digit numbers is this nested loop:

```
for (int both_digits = 2; both_digits * 2 <= total_digits; both_digits++)
{
  for (int first_digit = 1; first_digit < both_digits; first_digit++)
  {
    int second_digit = both_digits - first_digit;

    if (CheckAggregateNumber(aggregate_number, first_digit, second_digit))
      return true;
  }
}
```

Easiest way to implement `CheckAggregateNumber` function is through string comparison. First convert aggregate number to string. Then in a loop generate strings that should be substrings of aggregate number using first and second number and compare these substrings with appropriate parts of aggregate number. If everything checks out until end return true, otherwise return false. Here's some pseudo code:

```
aggregate_string = aggregate_number as string;
first_number = aggregate_string.Substring(0, first_digit) as int;
second_number = aggregate_string.Substring(first_digit, second_digit) as int;
index_on_aggregate = first_digit + second_digit;

begin loop
  new_number = first_number + second_number;
  new_string = new_number as string;

  if (new_string == aggregate_string.Substring(index_on_aggregate, new_string.Length)
    return false;

  first_number = second_number;
  second_number = new_number;
  index_on_aggregate = index_on_aggregate + new_string.Length;

  if (index_on_aggregate == aggregate_string.Length)
    return true;
end loop
```